# Force chrome on android to open facebook profile in a native android facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, google-chrome, android-intent

I want user to be send to native Facebook app when he will click a link on a web page in chrome on android (to a certain facebook profile). As a fallback, when native app is not installed, i want user to be sent to a webpage.

First I tried this `a(href='fb://page/varlamov')` but it doesn't work at all if app is not installed. Then i tried with intent `a(href="intent://profile/varlamov/#Intent;scheme=katana;package=com.facebook.katana;end")` but I can't construct the right `url`. The one above always send user to Play Market.

What is the `href` attribute of the A tag that will send a user to the native Facebook app to certain profile?

And is it possible to send user not to Play Market but to a Facebook website in case when native app is not installed?